# Properly remap vim numpad keys when numlock is off

Tags: vim

I want to remap my numpad so that even if numlock is off, I still have it print numbers.
This is obviously a fairly common task - it has been asked multiple times around the internet, and has its own page dedicated to it (though the page is putty-specific):

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings

Whenever it gets asked online, the answer seems to always be the same - a copy-paste of the lines from that guide:

```
:inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
:inoremap <Esc>Or 2
:inoremap <Esc>Os 3
:inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
:inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
:inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
:inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
:inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
:inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
:inoremap <Esc>Op 0
:inoremap <Esc>On .
:inoremap <Esc>OQ /
:inoremap <Esc>OR *
:inoremap <Esc>Ol +
:inoremap <Esc>OS -
:inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't always work. It certainly works for putty - I can confirm that, but right now, I'm using Fedora 31, with the regular Gnome Terminal, and with those lines in my .vimrc file, if I hit a numpad key with the numlock disabled, the keys either act as arrow keys (2,4,6,8), or Home, End, Pg Up, Pg Down.

One thing I can do is this instead (or in addition to the other mappings):

```
inoremap ^[OF 1
inoremap ^[OB 2
inoremap ^[[6~ 3
inoremap ^[OD 4
inoremap ^[OE 5
inoremap ^[OC 6
inoremap ^[OH 7
inoremap ^[OA 8
inoremap ^[[5~ 9
inoremap ^[[2~ 0
inoremap ^[[3~ .
inoremap ^[Oo /
inoremap ^[Oj *
inoremap ^[Ok +
inoremap ^[Om -
inoremap ^[OM <Enter>
```

I got these key combinations but simply hitting Ctrl+V, and my numpad keys to see what signal was being sent when the numlock was off. This works, and my numpad keys work as expected now. Except there's a problem. These signals are exactly the same as the other keys send. This means that now, if I actually hit my left arrow key in insert mode, it prints 4 instead of moving left. Same for the other arrow keys, and the Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys.

This is obviously inconvenient, because in insert mode, you can't use hjkl to navigate, and now, the arrow keys don't work either.

I understand the reason this happens - with numlock off, my 7 key on the numpad sends the exact same code that the Home button does, so if I override that, it effects both the 7 button (when the numlock is off), and the actual Home button.

Is there any kind of smart fix for this? Or is this inherently impossible to map without effecting the real arrow buttons, and Home/End/PgUp/PgDown buttons?

Failing that, is vim capable of enabling numlock when it starts up?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552591/281844). Not sure if it matches your situation exactly, but if it does, then you might need to patch the sources to support the keypad properly...

Comment: Did you try mapping `<kHome>` and friends?

Comment: @romainl not until you suggested it. Just tried it, and they didn't match any of my numpad keys when the numlock is off